# Navigation Drawer: Gmail vs AppCompatv7 v21

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am trying to change my Navigation Drawer to resemble that of the new Gmail App. I am using AppCompatv7 - v21, and have the updated sdk. What is it that i am missing? Please refer to the images below.

Gmail Navigation:

[image]

The navigation drawer, moves over the toolbar.

My current Navigation:

[image]

The navigation drawer, comes below the toolbar.

[EDIT]

This was my earlier XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_with_spinner" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/drawer_list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now as per the suggestion from pedro, I tried to move the toolbar inside drawerlayout.

Here is my new xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_with_spinner" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/drawer_list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my current code in onCreate()

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        spinner = (Spinner) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);
```

Now, i don't even see the toolbar. Here is the image.

[image]

[EDIT]

Here is my new layout. This works.. thanks again pedro...

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_with_spinner" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/drawer_list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put your toolbar inside your Drawer Layout.

Here is an example of a XML taken [from this Github Project:](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.poliveira.apps.materialtests.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I tried to put the toolbar inside the drawerlayout, but now i don't see the toolbar at all. Can you look at my edited question?

Comment: Wrap your toolbar and your framelayout inside a linearlayout. Check my example XML

Comment: Thanks, now it works... I tried to add linearlayout before and for some reason it crashed. Seems like i messed it up back then. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Its adding view on main view.. I want to add in `ListView` of `NavigationDrawer`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new layout. This works.. thanks again pedro...

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_with_spinner" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/drawer_list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]